# I have jks file can I update the app with new package name? Will I lose my previous downloads?

Tags: jks, package-name, app-update

I have a client who had hired some other developer previously and was unhappy with them so he decided to hire us but now the issue is that we are building the app from scratch.

Client wants to retain his previous downloads so he has got the JKS file. Our concern is whether we can upload a new app with new package name with same JKS file then will google playstore treat it as a new update of the app or new app altogether losing all the previous downloads.

Answer (score 0):

If you gone upload same application with different package name then  Google play will consider it as entirely new app and you gone lose all your previous customers. The JKS file with package name uniquely identify an application on PS.

I had a friend who has lost JKS file so he was not able to push update. Later, he had to upload same app with different JKS. He lost all his customer base.